# Ansible Dictionary value not set

Tags: json, loops, dictionary, ansible

I'm trying to fill a value in a dictionary with ansible but apparently is not doing it.

I do like this:

```
- name: Fill with zeros
  set_fact:
    item: "{{ item | combine(zero_fill, recursive=true) }}"
  vars:
    zero_fill: { 'json' : { 'data': { 'result': [{ 'value' : ["0.0","0.0"]}]}}}
  when: item.json.data.result == []
  with_items:
    - "{{ requests.results }}"
```

One item from this variable is like this:

```
{
...
"json": {
   "data": {
     "result": [],
     "resultType": "vector"
     }
   }
...
}
```

The point is that in the output of this task I do see the value added, but when I print it just right after the task, the value is not there.

Comment: Ansible's dictionaries are immutable. You have to create a new one. Simple structures should be used.

Comment: When you are modifying `item`, you are not modifying it in the loop or in the original data, you are just creating an `item` variable "globally". You can see this by doing `- debug: var=item` after your loop

Answer (score 1):

For example, create a new list *results_zf* and update the dictionary *json.data* with *zero_fill* when *json.data.result* is an empty list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        results_zf: "{{ results_zf|default([]) + [_item] }}"
      loop: "{{ requests.results }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ (item.json.data.result|length > 0)|
                   ternary(item,
                           {'json': {'data': item.json.data|combine(zero_fill)}})
                           }}"
```

Limit the dictionary *zero_fill* to the attribute *result*

```yaml
    zero_fill:
      'result': [{'value': ["0.0","0.0"]}]
```